# True or False? Continuous Functions #2

Tags: real-analysis

If functions $f+g:\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, then so is the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I feel like this is true, but I'm not sure how to justify my answer.

Comment: Try $f=(f+g)-g$. Subtraction is a continuous function.

Comment: So the statement is true because the difference of two continuous functions will also be continuous.

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only to remember that the (algebraic) sum of continuous functions is also a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also show this directly using the triangle inequality
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = \big|[f(x)+g(x)]-[f(y)+g(y)]+[g(y)-g(x)]\big|\\ \leq \big|[f(x)+g(x)]-[f(y)+g(y)]\big| + \big| g(x)-g(y)\big|
$$
and you have control over the right hand side because you know that $f+g$ and $g$ are continuous.